# jQuery-Codeigniter. Deleting second picture fail

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have an page with selected product and pictures. I want to delete data about pictures from DB and folders and update page via jQuery ajax.

Firstly I try do it using `<a href>` and I can delete one picture with updating page successfully, but after URL was changed (to end was added '#'), so script stopped sending GET (this part is commented, you can find below )

Secondly I added button and use `.click()`, then `.on` for event. Also first picture deletes second not, deletes only after refreshing. Second attempt - nothing change, like button without event.

controller main.php:

```
       function del_image($picture_id){

             $this->load->model('admin/Product_crud');
            $data['picture_name'] = $this->Product_crud->get_picture_name($picture_id);
            //var_dump($data);
             unlink('uploads/100/'.$data['picture_name'][0]->url);

             $data['product_id'] = $this->Product_crud->find_product_id_from_picture($picture_id);
             $this->Product_crud->del_picture_from_db($picture_id);
            $data['picture'] = $this->Product_crud->get_picture($data['product_id'][0]->product_id);

            $update_html = $this->Product_crud->create_picture_output($data['picture']);
            echo json_encode($update_html);



              //$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
         }
```

model product_crud.php:

```
      function create_picture_output($pictures){
         $output = NULL;
         $output .="<table border='1'>";
          foreach ($pictures as $picture){

              $output .=  "<tr>";
              $output .= "<td><a class='del_picture'  href='".$picture->picture_id."'><img title='Удалить' src='".base_url()."images/del.png'> </a></td>
              <td><img src='".base_url()."uploads/100/".$picture->url."'></td>
               <td><input class='del_picture' type='button' name='del'  value='".$picture->picture_id."'><img title='Удалить' src='".base_url()."images/del.png'> </td>";

                      $output .= "</tr>";

        }
           $output .="</table>";
           return $output;
        }
```

view form_edit_product.php
...............

```
       echo "<div id='result_table'>";

       echo "<table border='1'>";


       foreach ($url as $picture){

       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<td><a class='del_picture' href='".$picture_id[$l]."'><img             title='Удалить' src='".base_url()."images/del.png'></a></td>
              <td><img src='".base_url()."uploads/100/".$picture."'></td>
              <td><input class='del_picture' type='button' name='del' value='".$picture_id[$l]."'><img title='Удалить' src='".base_url()."images/del.png'></td>";
            $l++;
            echo "</tr>";
         }


          ?>

         </table>
         </div>
```

script:

```
   $(".del_picture").on("click", function(){
     /* var picture_id =  $(this).attr("href");
        var myurl = '<?php echo base_url()."admin/main/del_image/"?>';
         $(this).attr("href",'#'); */

         var picture_id =  $(this).attr("value");
          var myurl = '<?php echo base_url()."admin/main/del_image/"?>';

          var url = myurl + picture_id
       $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(update_html){
                $("#result_table").html(update_html);

            } 
        });    

    });
```

Issue is somewhere URL/jQuery script/GET. May be after updating event not adding to button...

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax if you want but you don't really have to. There's another way. In you controller at the end of your del_image() method after this line:

```
$this->Product_crud->del_picture_from_db($picture_id);
```

Put this code

```
$ref = $this->input->server('HTTP_REFERER', TRUE);
redirect($ref, 'location');
```

This will get the last url and refresh page after photo has been deleted. You don't need to update html and no json needed.

If you want to, you can use ajax too, but there's some mistakes you have in your code. For example, you need to delete dataType json since you are using GET request. Also when you are creating your url, you are missing semicolon before ending php statement.

Comment: Fixed semicolon, thanks. I would like use jquery as I learning it. Why dataType must be deleted. Could you advice ? I'm still searching answer, but without success.

Comment: Data type should be deleted because you are using GET request. GET request will put your data in the url. When you specify dataType as json usually means you are making post request and sending data in a body of post request. Data type can be varios things like xml, encoded string, json. If you are only sending 1 object in your case ID, you put it in GET. If you would have to send multiple objects, you would make POST request and there choose dataType. Example: {"name": "Mike", "username":"mike","city":"new yok"}  - that would be json.

Comment: I wrap up jQuery code $(".result_table").on("click", ".del_picture", function(){ .....});

Comment: and it started working but with delaying about 200-350 ms. By default jQuery uses async request..

Comment: so do you still have issue with this?? How big are the pics you are trying to delete?